# Calculate the coordinates of 4 edges in google maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps, coordinates, latitude-longitude, android-maps-v2

I am using the google maps api v2 for my new google maps app. And I wondered how to calculate the coordinates of 4 edges of the current screen position so that I can search for markers that are directly in the camera view. Any ideas about how it is possible to achieve ? I thought about something with the center of the camera view and zoom but can't figure out how to continue.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the proper answer to get the coordinates of upper right corner and down left corner:

```
mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {
                LatLngBounds bounds = mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
                //fetchData(bounds);
                ne = bounds.northeast;
                sw = bounds.southwest;
                //new DownloadJSON().execute();
                //Log.e("LatLngs"," southwest: "+sw+" northeast: "+ne);
            }
        });
```